# Name for JS UI Component

Tags: javascript, sliders, component

There's a text-dragging UI component I want to use, [which can be seen in detail here](http://worrydream.com/Tangle/) (drag the cookies!).

This is a pretty common idea, and is used a lot in native production applications. I would just make it, but there's probably a thousand JS libraries for one.

My problem, is *I don't know the standard name for it*! Any search for text sliders or text scrolling leads to other types of UI components.

What do you call this thing?

Comment: To be honest I've never seen that anywhere until now and I don't if it's just me but it works horrible on a mobile device.

Comment: True that, but the application I intend it for does not have to be mobile-responsive.

Comment: Maybe Swipe(able) Input Control? Haven't seen this before either..

Comment: Even on a desktop, I don't think its behaviour is obvious. It's affordable leads us to expec it's a link, when in reality it behaves as either a numerical stepper or a drop-down box. I know those two components are probably clunkier than what you want, but at least it provides immediately recognizable cues as to what is modifiable and how it works.

Comment: True. It only like is because, when you do understand it, it makes for fast changes in context, which is what I am looking for. This is for a Single Page App where users are few and trained on it. But maybe it should borrow a different color than a hyperlink, such as orange or something.

Comment: One could also make it more structured as it is rolled over, I suppose, such as by revealing a light background / border, giving it a more solid effect.

Answer (score 2):

NumericBox control is it called in Windows, although the visual is really a box, but the swipe interaction is part of that control.

Source: http://www.telerik.com/windows-8/numeric-textbox-html

Where might make sense to search: Autodesk uses these swipe/scroll sensitive controls and they use Vault API and DevExpress frameworks for their UI.

Comment: based on that link I guess you could call the control a 'numeric input' but the actual gesture/action could be called 'Swipe to Increment'